# Buck Boost Driver to switch 2 LED chains

Tags: led, buck, boost, led-driver

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ8SIX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm working on a project to turn 2 LED strings (each containing 6 HB LEDs).
Here is my question. 
The Buck Boost driver I'm using is an ZXLD1371. 
Connecting one chain is pretty straight forward. But if I wanted to connect two chains to the circuit, Can I use 2 Series pass transistors (FETs) to connect each cathode of the LED chain to the Supply?

The Pass transistors will be interfaced to a micro controller and Will be made sure that they don't both turn ON at the same time.

Can you think of any issues with this setup? TBH, I think this will work. But its good to get a 2nd opinion :)

Please see the circuit included.
P.S. Values not actual.

Datasheet of BB controller : http://www.diodes.com/_files/datasheets/ZXLD1370.pdf

Cheers
Labmat

Comment: The basic idea sounds good.  Why not post a schematic, and let someone check it over?  There's a schematic editor built in to the site.  Edit your question and press CTRL M, then draw the schematic.  Add notes indicating voltages.  Also add links to the datasheets for the components you will use.

Comment: I'm going to vote close too broad, since in 20 hours no response to the above comment has come. Once it's closed you can still edit to clarify.

Comment: Hey,Sorry. I was quite busy.
Ill upload a schematic ASAP.

Cheers

Comment: That looks soooo bizarre.  But, the datasheet backs it up.  The real question would then be "is the circuitry around M2 and M3 correct for the MCU to control the LEDs."

Comment: the Circuitry around M2 and M3 can be adjusted by either using a PMOS with a BJT ( MCU --> BJT --> PMOS)
Or by using a NMOS and a suitable gate driver that is TTL compatible.

My main question would be ("can you see any problems with driving the circuit like this?)

Comment: Sorry for the edit. 
When the Mosfet is ON, the LED will be connected to the VCC.
when it is OFF, what will the LED see? Im guessing it will see a High Resistance ..
Am I right?